# TensorFlow - Decoding images in a given shape from TF records

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to read images from TFrecords file. The images vary in shapes. After reading, I want to preserve their shape which is why I pass the height, width and depth parameters appropriately. But the code just doesn't print anything after the set_shape command. I initialized the session in the main function. Is there a way to get the values of height,w,d tensors so that I can pass it to set_shape? How do I fix this? Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
def read_and_decode(sess,filename_queue):
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
      features={
          'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
          'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
          'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
          'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
          'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      })

  # Convert from a scalar string tensor (whose single string has
  # length mnist.IMAGE_PIXELS) to a uint8 tensor with shape
  # [mnist.IMAGE_PIXELS].
  image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
  image.set_shape([sess.run(features['height']),sess.run(features['width']),sess.run(features['depth'])])
```

Here's my main function:

```
def main(argv=None):
   with tf.Graph().as_default():
      sess=tf.Session()
      pdb.set_trace()
      load_inputs(sess,FLAGS.batch_size)
```

and load_input() function which calls the read_and_decode().

```
def load_inputs(sess,batch_size):
    filenames='/home/dp1248/ICR_TF/original_iam_test_words.tfrecords'

    # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filenames],num_epochs=1)

    # Even when reading in multiple threads, share the filename
    # queue.
    image, label = read_and_decode(sess,filename_queue)
```

Comment: Solution: This is how I got around this. 
height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
  width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)
  depth = tf.cast(features['depth'], tf.int32)

  image_shape = tf.stack([height, width, depth])
  image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
  image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)